# Google maps - override style

Tags: html, css, google-maps-api-2

I am using the Google Maps api on my website and I have been experimenting with making a "fullscreen map" using a class toggle with jquery.

I am running into a problem in that the div which contains my google map appears to inherit some styles from the API which I am having trouble removing/overriding - does anyone know if I can do this?

From firebug, the Div is showing -

```
style="position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); z-index: 1;"
```

The CSS class I'm toggling to make it fullscreen is -

```
#map.fullscreen { position: fixed; width:100%; height: 100%; z-index: 60; left: 0; top: 0; }
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery to remove the `style` attribute:

```
$(function()
{
    $('#map.fullscreen').removeAttr('style');
});
```